# How to convert milliseconds to seconds units and display them in textView?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to convert milliseconds to seconds units?

For example the seekBar values are from 100 to 1000 and I want to display the units if they are under 1000(second) as 0.1 0.2 0.3....0.9 then 1

```
private var counter: Long = 0

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val seek = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
        seek.min = 100
        seek.max = 1000
        seek.progress = 500
        counter = seek.progress.toLong()

        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(
                    seekBar: SeekBar?,
                    progress: Int,
                    fromUser: Boolean
                ) {
                    counter = progress.toLong()
                    textView.text = (counter/1000).toString()
```

The line:

`textView.text = (counter/1000).toString()`

make it that if the bar is on the right side it will display 1 but then to the left it will display only 0.

and I want that on the right end it will display 1 but then when moving it to the left it will display 0.9 then 0.8 then 0.7.....0.1

I tried:

`textView.text = (counter/1000).toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the data type of `counter` from `Long` to `Float` or `Double`. `Long` only allows integer values.

```
private var counter: Float = 0.0F
...
counter = seek.progress.toFloat()
```